# Javascript/jQuery: Basic auth over multiple requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, basic-authentication

I am sending an Ajax-GET-requests using basic auth:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: url,
  beforeSend: function(xhr){
     xhr.setRequestHeader( "Authorization", "Basic "+btoa("username:password"));
     xhr.setRequestHeader( "Accept", "application/json" );
    },
  success: function(data){
    console.warn(data);
  }
});
```

This is working perfectly fine - but do I have to send the username/password on every request?

This would mean, that I have to ask the user for his username/password on every request / or store it in Javascript, which is not very safe.

Is there any way to send the username/password only once, even for multiple requests?

Thank you very much!

Comment: it would be better if you implement a token authentication system. So that the user after an authentication receives a token that is then used to authenticate the rest of the requests. But you shouldn't be sending passwords through Javascript. its insecure

Comment: Yes, you see it perfectly. A better approach would be Oauth2 with Bearer tokens where you would send the username/password once (password grant type) and get an access token that needs to be added to every request header you send.

Comment: sending passwords with ajax calls all the time is not the best way. use tokens as suggested also by @laszlokiss88